# OpenID on a Java Server

Tags: java, openid

I am working on a project that requires user authentication both from a web server and from a custom java socket server (running on netty).

It would be great if I could use OpenID for user login... but as I'm reading about it, seems it is for webservers only...

Can I use OpenID from a proprietary socket server as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying that you want both your web application and your netty-socket-application to be authenticated via OpenID?

As you have found out, the web application part is (fairly) easy. The socket is quite a bit trickier since I assume that you're not speaking HTTP and the clients are not browsers - and that last part is really the key, since your clients will have to understand that the challenge from your socket application means that they should redirect to WhateverOpenID and be authorized and then be redirected back...

You could consider a Single Sign On solution where any user would have to be authorized on the web app first and then given a secure token to use as auth for the socket server?

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks! That's a good idea about forcing the login through the web and then just checking the database